# In number theory, what does $exp_{q}m$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation

[I saw this notation in this math problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjqpb.png)

I don't think it means $q^m$ or has anything to do with $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From context I believe it means 'the number of times that $q$ divides $m$' (or in the linked problem statement, $m-1$). In this case, $\mathop{exp}_q(m-1)=\alpha$ is equivalent to saying that $q^\alpha\mid(m-1)$ but $q^{\alpha+1}\not\mid(m-1)$ (or, alternately and relevant to the problem, $m\equiv 1\pmod {q^\alpha}$ but $m\neq 1\pmod {q^{\alpha+1}}$).

Comment: Thanks, tried that out and it makes perfect sense!